# Is there any java library to format SQL?

Tags: java

I am looking for a simple library [free] wherein i can use something like this:-

```
String formattedSQL = xyzLib.format ( sql );
```

Is there any such library? Or is there a way to format the SQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not aware of a library that does this, but you might look at Hibernate's [SQL formatter](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/2964ecbf1b74003fcc337b0574487c724638fe94/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/BasicFormatterImpl.java). From my experience it does a pretty good job at prettifying SQL statements, but as always, it might not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Yohei Yamana (vertical-blank) has written an open source, pure-Java standalone, zero-dependencies [SQL Formatter](https://github.com/vertical-blank/sql-formatter). It is available from maven central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.vertical-blank</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql-formatter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```